# Inconsistent response from Postgres DB on similar queries

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-rds

I have a Postgres DB hosted on Amazon RDS with 150GB of stogare, 8GB RAM and 2vCPUs. The DB has a table with 320 columns and 20 million rows as of now. The problem I am facing is that the response time of the DB queries has reduced quite a lot as we began inserting more data. At 18 million rows, the DB response was quite fast. But after inserting another 2 million rows, the performance reduced quite a lot. I did a simple query as follows

```
explain analyze SELECT * from "data_table" WHERE foreign_key_id = 7 ORDER BY "TimeStamp" DESC LIMIT 1;
```

The response for the above as follows

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..90.21 rows=1 width=2552) (actual time=650065.806..650065.807 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan Backward using "data_table_TimeStamp_219314ec" on data_table  (cost=0.43..57250559.80 rows=637678 width=2552) (actual time=650065.803..650065.803 rows=1 loops=1)
        Filter: (asset_id = 7)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 4910074
Planning time: 44.072 ms
Execution time: 650066.004 ms
```

I ran another query with a different id for the foreign key and the result was as shown below

```
explain analyze SELECT * from "data_table" WHERE foreign_key_id = 1 ORDER BY "TimeStamp" DESC LIMIT 1;

Limit  (cost=0.43..13.05 rows=1 width=2552) (actual time=2.749..2.750 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan Backward using "data_table_TimeStamp_219314ec" on data_table  (cost=0.43..57250559.80 rows=4539651 width=2552) (actual time=2.747..2.747 rows=1 loops=1)
        Filter: (asset_id = 1)
Planning time: 0.496 ms
Execution time: 2.927 ms
```

As you can see two different queries of the same type give highly different results. The number of records with foreign_key_id=1 is 11 million while that with foreign_key_id=7 is about 1 million.

I am not able to figure out why this is happening. There is a huge delay in response for all foreign_key_id's except for foreign_key_id=1. The first query has a line where Filter removed rows. Which is not there in the second query.

Could anyone help me with understanding this issue?

Additional Information
The TimeStamp is indexed using btree
A small amount of data insertion is being done every 10 minutes. Occasionally we also insert bulk data(5-6 million rows) using scripts.

Comment: Its possible that the difference in response time is due to the data already being in memory ('hot') at the time you ran the second query.

Comment: @GregoryArenius I checked for that. Repeated query was still giving the same result

Answer (score 1):

You could add index to generate different execution plan:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON data_table(foreign_key_id, "TimeStamp" DESC);
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out. Can you explain why there is so much of difference in the response?

Comment: This helped to cut down the time significantly. But the time-range queries are still taking longer time. (TimeStamp > "some_time_stamp" AND TimeStamp <"another_time_stamp"). Even for a month's data which translate to 200,000 records, it is taking 15 seconds.

Comment: @Cognoscis "Can you explain why there is so much of difference in the response?" I provided index that cover that specific query. It won't solve all your problems. Please note that `TimeStamp > "some_time_stamp" AND TimeStamp <"another_time_stamp"` is entire new query than `WHERE foreign_key_id = 7 ORDER BY "TimeStamp" DESC`